# Calculate SUM from different tables with condition

Tags: sql-server-2005, sum, between

I have 4 SQL Server 2005 tables: MainTable, Info, Repairs, Maintenance

MainTable table:

```
MainID, PlateNo
1, A123
2, D222
```

Info table:

```
InfoID, MainID, Location
1, 1, California
2, 2, Ohio
```

Repairs table:

```
RepairID, MainID, Cost, InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate
1, 1, 250, 3423523, 12/10/2010
2, 1, 340, 5634534, 08/11/2010
3, 2, 125, 9258143, 10/02/2010
```

Maintenance table:

```
MaintenanceID, MainID, Cost, InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate
1, 1, 223, 9694534, 07/03/2009
2, 2, 830, 4259943, 01/02/2011
```

All tables are linked by MainID from MainTable.

I want to get SUM(Cost) from Repairs, SUM(Cost) from Maintenance between a two dates (InvoiceDate) for a given 'Location' from Info table for every PlateNo.

Comment: What have you tried that does not work? Is your code even close? Or have you no idea where to start?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this query using derived tables.  You could just as easily use common table expressions.

```
Select Main.MainId,
       Main.PlateNo,
       Info.Location,
       MaintenanceCosts.MaintenanceCost,
       RepairCosts.RepairCost
From   Main
       Inner Join Info
         On Main.MainId = Info.MainId
       Left Join (
         Select MainId, Sum(Cost) As MaintenanceCost
         From   Maintenance
         Where  InvoiceDate >= @StartDate
                And InvoiceDate < @EndDate
         Group By MainId
         ) As MaintenanceCosts
         On Main.MainId = MaintenanceCosts.MainId
       Left Join (
         Select MainId, Sum(Cost) As RepairCost
         From   Repairs
         Where  InvoiceDate >= @StartDate
                And InvoiceDate < @EndDate
         Group By MainId
         ) As RepairCosts
         On Main.MainId = RepairCosts.MainId
Where  Info.Location = @Location
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
select 

isnull(sum(a.[ Cost]) + sum(b.[ Cost]),0) cost,
a.[ MainID],a.[ InvoiceDate]

from 

[maintanen] a inner join 
[repairs] b 

on a.[ MainID]=b.[ MainID]


group by a.[ MainID],a.[ InvoiceDate]
```

COMBINE LOCATION